# Maven failsafe plugin doesn't run parallel Test

Tags: java, maven, testing, maven-failsafe-plugin, parallel-testing

I have a Maven POM file and when I provide parallel execution options, I dont see any signs of parallel execution in the logs. And XML debugging is driving me nuts. Any thoughts what is wrong here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>com.xxx.xxxx.testing.ranger</groupId>
      <artifactId>ranger-parent</artifactId>
      <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
   </parent>
   <artifactId>ranger-api-tests</artifactId>
   <name>Ranger API Tests</name>
   <description>Ranger API integration tests. Depends on the Ranger test framework project.</description>
   <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <test.groups />
      <surefire.and.failsafe.report.dir>C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Projects/LearnCubeAPIIT/tests/target</surefire.and.failsafe.report.dir>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <!-- Granite Testing framework -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.xxx.xxxx.testing.ranger</groupId>
         <artifactId>ranger-api-it-framework</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
         <version>2.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
         <version>3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
         <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
         <version>2.16</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>4.11</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
               <parallel>classes</parallel>
               <threadCount>4</threadCount>
               <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
               <groups>${test.groups}</groups>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>integration-test</goal>
                     <goal>verify</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <reporting>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
               <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
               <reportSet>
                  <id>integration-tests</id>
                  <reports>
                     <report>failsafe-report-only</report>
                     <report>report-only</report>
                  </reports>
               </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </reporting>
</project>
```

Logs from run - http://pastebin.com/WkCDwYzJ

Question - When parallel execution options are passed to failsafe plugin, how are the logs supposed to look like to confirm that parallel execution of tests is taking place?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that when I set debug option for maven to execute, I noticed that parallelExecution is being set to false

```
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4--1057774753
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.12.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.12.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.12.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:jar:1.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.8
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG]   Excluded: classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:2.0.9
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4--1057774753, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7987aeca]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) basedir = /Users/nallagun/Git/testing/Ranger/tests
[DEBUG]   (s) childDelegation = false
[DEBUG]   (s) classesDirectory = /Users/nallagun/Git/testing/Ranger/tests/target/classes
[DEBUG]   (s) disableXmlReport = false
[DEBUG]   (s) enableAssertions = true
[DEBUG]   (s) forkMode = once
[DEBUG]   (s) junitArtifactName = junit:junit
[DEBUG]   (s) localRepository =        id: local
      url: file:///Users/nallagun/.m2/repository/
   layout: none

[DEBUG]   (s) parallel = classes
[DEBUG]   (f) parallelMavenExecution = false
[DEBUG]   (s) perCoreThreadCount = true
```

Any Idea why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant pom sections in the question body.

Comment: I am having issues with XML formatting, so didnt want to mess up the post :(

Comment: That log you're seeing is related to the maven-surefire-plugin. I can't see configuration of this plugin. Do you have surefire configuration somewhere in your parent pom?

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, make sure you're forcing a specific jUnit provider, since older versions (<4.7) are known to have [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600090/maven-surefire-unable-to-fork-parallel-test-execution/3608016#3608016) with concurrent execution.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.16</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
      <version>2.16</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

You can use the `forkCount` for concurrent execution option instead of `parallel`. I find it more flexible and since each test run in its own JVM, you would have less concurrency issues that might make your test results non-deterministic. These configurations apply to `maven-surefire-plugin` and `maven-failsafe-plugin`.

```
<forkCount>8</forkCount>
<reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
```

You can combine `forkCount` and `parallel`, but the different possible combinations of `forkCount`, `reuseForks`, etc make things more complicated. Note this from the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html#):

> When using reuseForks=true and a forkCount value larger than one, test
>   classes are handed over to the forked process one-by-one. Thus,
>   parallel=classes would not change anything. However, you can use
>   parallel=methods: classes are executed in forkCount concurrent
>   processes, each of the processes can then use threadCount threads to
>   execute the methods of one class in parallel.

I'm not sure the reports would tell you if tests ran in concurrent mode or not, but the way I know they are running is by using `top` or `htop` (on Linux or OS X). Here's a screenshot of one my test runs. You can see multiple JVMs running tests and consuming CPU. Also my tests run much faster in this fashion.

[image: htop]

Comment: Thanks, another bonus point question, how are you handling test logs? Do you let failsafe handle them or you use your own wrapper?

Comment: I did try your updated answer by adding the dependency plugin, but doesn't help

Comment: Did you add forkCount?

Comment: Add that to pom. Also add similar configuration for surefire.

Comment: maven-failsafe-plugin-v2.18.1. Doesn't work. Still single process :(

Comment: @Boj you solution didn't work in my case. I've multiple test cases in single class but they don't run in parallel. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115143/maven-failsafe-plugin-does-not-execute-test-cases-from-single-class-in-parallel