# maven-failsafe-plugin does not execute test cases from single class in parallel mode

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-failsafe-plugin

I've single test class with multiple test cases, which I would like to execute in parallel mode.

I've below setup in pom.xml

But instead of executing in parallel mode, test cases are being executed in sequence.

Please clarify what may be going wrong here ?

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>            
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly adding parallel configuration in maven-failsafe-plugin is not working (May  be a bug.)

But we can set parallel attribute and thread count in surefire plugin configuration.

Internally **maven-failsafe-plugin** downloads **maven-surefire-plugin** plugin.

So we can explicitly provide dependency on maven-surefire-plugin having parallel configuration.

I  have tested , method are getting executed in parallel.

For more know how on running testcase in parallel and more configuration  parameters click [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html).

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                </configuration>
             <plugin>
```

Working pom.

```
<project>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
<artifactId>my-module</artifactId>
<version>1</version>


<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>3</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <parallel>methods</parallel>
                <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>

        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: Are you using  JUnit 4.7+? .If not please use junit version greater than 4.7.

Comment: I'm using 4.12 and have explicitly mentioned in my pom.xml as well. It's really strange why your solution doesn't work. Please let me know if it works in your case ? if yes can you please share your pom.xml ?

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml?

Comment: Thanks a ton for your time, but the problem with this approach is all the test methods' steps are getting mixed up. Instead of single test method getting executed fully on a device, it is sending instruction to random devices. "...but you may be more vulnerable towards race conditions or other unexpected and hard to reproduce behavior..." from documentation. I'm not sure if there is bug with this plugin as well.