# Maven - Failsafe plugin is not running cucumber tests in parallel

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-failsafe-plugin, cucumber-serenity

I am trying to setup serenity cucumber tests to run in parallel

I have added all the necessary configuration that have been mentioned but for some reason tests are executed in a single thread. I tried various combinations with forkCount, threadCount, parallel, useUnlimitedThreadCounts etc nothing seems to work.

Also tried having a dependency for JUnit 4 and 5 which didnt work as well.

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <properties>
        <serenity.version>2.2.5</serenity.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>2.2.5</serenity.maven.version>
        <serenity.cucumber5.version>2.2.2</serenity.cucumber5.version>
        <cucumber.version>5.6.0</cucumber.version>
        <selenium.version>3.141.59</selenium.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Cucumber -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Serenity -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber5</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.cucumber5.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Selenium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                    <forkCount>2C</forkCount>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The maven debug logs for verify indicates parallelMavenExecution is set to false for some reason.

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M4:integration-test from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M4, parent: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4f8e5cde]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M4:integration-test' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) additionalClasspathElements = []
[DEBUG]   (s) basedir = /Users/vinothraj/IdeaProjects/hiscox-usa-portal-testsuite
[DEBUG]   (s) childDelegation = false
[DEBUG]   (s) classpathDependencyExcludes = []
[DEBUG]   (s) defaultClassesDirectory = /target/classes
[DEBUG]   (s) dependenciesToScan = []
[DEBUG]   (s) disableXmlReport = false
[DEBUG]   (s) enableAssertions = true
[DEBUG]   (f) excludedEnvironmentVariables = []
[DEBUG]   (f) forkCount = 2C
[DEBUG]   (s) forkMode = once
[DEBUG]   (s) forkedProcessExitTimeoutInSeconds = 30
[DEBUG]   (s) junitArtifactName = junit:junit
[DEBUG]   (s) localRepository =       id: local
      url: file:///.m2/repository/
   layout: default
snapshots: [enabled => true, update => always]
 releases: [enabled => true, update => always]

[DEBUG]   (s) parallel = classes
[DEBUG]   (f) parallelMavenExecution = false
[DEBUG]   (s) parallelOptimized = true
[DEBUG]   (s) perCoreThreadCount = true
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First remove the `surefire-junit47` from maven-surefire-plugin. Furthermore If I correctly remember the docs of cucumber it supports only JUnit 4 which means you have to add at minimum a dependency to junit 4 to your project.

Comment: @khmarbaise - I added the surefire because of the answer in the post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716619/maven-failsafe-plugin-doesnt-run-parallel-test

I have the JUNIT dependency to 4.12. Thanks

Comment: First the mentioned post is 7 years old and was wrong at time of writing as it is today (has a dependency to the provider? etc. The question was about parallelisation). The JUnit 4.12 dependency is not visible in the posted pom? Furthermore a full working example on github or alike would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong value for `parallel`. You have to set it to methods or both. Otherwise Surefire will run all tests of your runner class serially.

> https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit
>
> Cucumber JUnit supports parallel execution of feature files across multiple threads. To enable this with maven set the parallel property to either methods or both.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- Use 2.22.1 or higher -->
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>  
            <configuration>
                <parallel>both</parallel>
                <threadCount>4</threadCount>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```